# virtual gateway iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, vpn, iproute

I'm trying to setup kind of simple networking configuration, but I cannot wrap my head around this. My goal is to make LAN clients go via VPN, while having the possibility to reach the server itself. Current setup:

GW machine:

```
VPN interface -> vpn0 [10.x.y.z]
LAN interface -> lan0 [172.16.1.0/24], machine itself is 172.16.1.1
```

I have created separate routing table for the vpn connection and I'm able to reach it; for example `ping -I vpn0 10.20.30.40` (machine in VPN network) works beautifully.
Currently I can enable VPN access for LAN clients if I do it like this:

```
ip rule add from 172.16.1.0/24 table vpntable
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.1.0/24 -o vpn0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, in this case clients cannot access the gateway machine (`172.16.1.1`) itself, which's expected. My goal is to be able to reach **BOTH** gateway machine and VPN one from the LAN side. I'm quite sure `MASQUERADE` is the culprit here, but I'm not sure what direction should I go to. I had two ideas in mind:

1. Create virtual interface via `dummy` module and try to have it configured as a "gateway" for LAN clients? Like by default they're able to reach `172.16.1.1` and if they do something like `ip route add 10.20.30.0/24 via 172.16.16.1`, where `172.16.16.1` is the address of that virtual interface; however I'm afraid I'll end up in lots of `SNAT` rules and it'll create even more overhead.
2. Policy based routing via connection marking? In this case clients don't have to do any additional steps.

GW machine is Ubuntu LTS, forwarding is on, iptables are empty except of the rule mentioned.

I'd appreciate any input on the topic. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

`vpntable` contains routing specific for the vpn network:

```
default via 10.20.1.1 dev vpn0
```

Comment: @A.B yes, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netfilter and NAT are not involved here, it's all about routing.

---

As the policy rule traverses *vpntable* first and this routing table always matches to provide an answer to the route lookup because of a default route, the *main* routing table is not used anymore when the gateway's own 172.16.1.1 is used. So there's nothing left to tell to use *lan0* anymore.

So while the initial route selection would use *lan0*:

```
$ ip route get to 172.16.1.2
172.16.1.2 dev lan0 src 172.16.1.1 uid 1000 
    cache
```

once this route is selected this will set the address to 172.16.1.1 part of 172.16.1.0/24 and thus will switch to using *vpn0*:

```
$ ip route get from 172.16.1.1 to 172.16.1.2
172.16.1.2 from 172.16.1.1 via 10.20.1.1 dev vpn0 table vpntable uid 1000 
    cache
```

The fix is to add an exception to stay on *lan0* in this case.

There are several ways to do this, all should solve the problem, usually first or last (the simplest) are used:

- specify LAN route in the VPN routing table

  ```
  ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 dev lan0 table vpntable
  ```
- or resolve LAN first for local traffic (the special `iif lo` means here *locally initiated traffic*, it doesn't really involve the *lo* interface) with a routing rule that calls the *main* routing table. Being added after it has a lower preference and is evaluated before the one calling the *vpntable* routing table:

  ```
  ip rule add iif lo to 172.16.1.0/24 lookup main
  ```
- or as a variant of previous bullet: jump over the VPN rule, directly to the rule calling the *main* routing table:

  ```
  ip rule add iif lo to 172.16.1.0/24 goto 32766
  ```
- or specify the interface instead of the address in the initial routing rule (which must be deleted):

  ```
  ip rule delete from 172.16.1.0/24 lookup vpntable
  ip rule add iif lan0 lookup vpntable
  ```

  That way it won't trigger for a local address since it isn't received from *lan0*.

Contrary to the first methods the last won't even allow to use the VPN by default on the gateway when binding to a source of 172.16.1.1 (which then would still get NATed by the MASQUERADE rule).

Comment: Thank you! Last bullet point did the trick